# Unable to get access token from google oauth

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to get access token via google oauth api, But I am getting invalid grant error.
It's working fine with my test app credentails, but it's not working with app which i send for approval.

Following is my code which i am using.

```
url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 

payload = {
"client_id": "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"code": "x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"grant_type": "authorization_code",
"redirect_uri":"https://app.gettheme.io/data-setup"
}

response = {
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Please let me know what am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authorization_code` flow of google. It is not simple steps.

The Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications in [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python)
, [there](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

[image]

It can't get the token by `curl` or `Postman` (normal HTTP call)

It can do by local servers like [`flask`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/)(Pythonb), [`express`](https://expressjs.com/)(node.js).

The demo code for python with two google libraries and `flask`.

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
```

#### Prepare Steps

#1 Create `google` project

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/
```

[image]

#2 Create OAuth Client ID
[image]

[image]

#3 Save `client_secret.json` from Google Developer
It will use a credential at python demo code.

[image]

[image]

#### Demo code

Save as `get-token.py` file name.

*Note, the port number should match your App's `Authorized redirect URIs` setting port.

At line 12's the secret copy from your App's credential page.
[image]

```py
import os
import flask
import json

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

SCOPES = ['openid','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '<your app secret>'

@app.route('/token')
def test_api_request():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect('login')

  # Load credentials from the session.
  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(**flask.session['credentials'])
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
  return json.dumps({
    'token': credentials.token,
    'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
    'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
    'client_id': credentials.client_id,
    'scopes': credentials.scopes})

@app.route('/login')
def authorize():
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline',include_granted_scopes='true')
  flask.session['state'] = state
  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/callback')
def oauth2callback():
  state = flask.session['state']
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
  authorization_response = flask.request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('test_api_request'))

def credentials_to_dict(credentials):
  return {'token': credentials.token,
          'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
          'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
          'client_id': credentials.client_id,
          'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
          'scopes': credentials.scopes}

if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  app.run('localhost', 3000, debug=True)
```

Run it

```
python get-token.py
```

Login by Browser

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result - `access token` will display in browser.

[image]

Comment: Okay, let me try this

Comment: Great answer! If i wanna use the returned token to authorize users to my application, what parts do I store in the database?

Comment: To store an `access token` into database can be a more secure option instead local storage or cookies but, storing tokens in a database can add complexity to your application. I think you needs to ask(or search) to stack over flow.