# Request to Get Google OAuth Access Token Failing

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, refresh-token

I'm trying to get a refresh token and use it to issue an access token, but the request to generate the access token isn't working.

I'm calling this API to get the refresh token:

URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth (GET)

```
    var params = {'client_id': '{MY_CLIENT_ID}',
                  'redirect_uri': '{MY_REDIRECT_URI}',
                  'response_type': 'code',
                  'scope': 'https://mail.google.com/',
                  'access_type': 'offline',
                  'prompt': 'consent'};
```

This request works properly and results in a token, but when I try to get the access token, the request fails with this error message:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Here is my request to get the access token:
URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token (POST)

```
x-www-form-urlencoded BODY: grant_type="refresh_token", client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}, client_secret={MY_CLIENT_SECRET}, refresh_token={THE TOKEN I JUST GOT}
```

[Here's a screenshot of my request in Postman.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddcsX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change token URL

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

You can the new access token by curl with refresh_token

```js
curl -X POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token \
  --silent \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d client_id=[YOUR CLIENT_ID] \
  -d client_secret=[YOUR CLIENT_SECRET] \
  -d refresh_token=[YOUR REFRESH TOKEN] \
  -d grant_type=refresh_token
```

##### Result by curl

[image]

##### Result by Postman

[image]

This code is how to get refresh_toke by node.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library'); // Corrected import statement
const fs = require('fs');

const CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json";
const SCOPES = ['openid', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'];
const PORT = 3000; // Port number need to change by your configuration.

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE);
let clientSecrets = JSON.parse(rawdata);

const app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: clientSecrets.web.client_secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
  clientSecrets.web.client_id,
  clientSecrets.web.client_secret,
  clientSecrets.web.redirect_uris[0] // This usually is the first URI in the array
);

app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  res.redirect(authUrl);
});

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;
  const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
  req.session.credentials = tokens;
  res.redirect('/token');
});

app.get('/token', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.credentials) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(req.session.credentials);
  res.json({
    token: req.session.credentials.access_token,
    refresh_token: req.session.credentials.refresh_token,
    token_uri: oAuth2Client.tokenUri,
    client_id: oAuth2Client._clientId,
    scopes: req.session.credentials.scope
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Access login by Browser

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

##### You can get the `refresh_token`

[image]

more detail explain in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767917/unable-to-get-access-token-from-google-oauth/75773584#75773584)

It will be describe "**how to save client_secret.json?**"

Comment: No problem, happy to code!

Answer (score 0):

To exchange a refresh token for a new access token looks something like this.  Its a HTTP POST call and the format of the body is URL Prams. Its not an object.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={REDACTED}&client_secret={REDACTED}&refresh_token={REDACTED}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm currently using form-urlencoded body params with the POST request (I just edited the original post to include a screenshot of my request). Is that what you mean? This type of request isn't working for me.

Comment: If you want to use postman check this https://youtu.be/jjCauMywU2Q?si=A4jmcc4LzmOXsXF5